# Gather multiple functions output on single route call and render to html in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Newbie to nodejs,trying to execute multiple functions output to html using nodejs,express and mysql as backend.Need to execute 20 functions on single routing call to combine the output of 20 functions and render as json to html.

My app.js function

```
    var express = require('express');
        var router = express.Router();
        var path        = require('path');
        var app = express();
        var todo = require('./modules/first');
        var todo1 = require('./modules/second');
        var connection = require('./connection');
        connection.init();
        app.get('/', function(req,res,next) {        
    Promise.all([todo.class1.getUsrCnt(),todo.class1.getTotlAmt(),todo.class1.getTotlOrdrCnt(),todo.class1.getTotlCntRcds(),todo.class1.getTotlScsRcds(),todo.class1.getTotlFailRcds(),todo.class1.getTotlAmtRcds()])
                   .then(function(allData) {
              res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://hostname:8183/");
        res.json({ message3: allData });
        });
      res.send(send response to html);
    })
app.get('/second', function(req,res,next) {        
    Promise.all([todo1.class2.getUsr........])
                   .then(function(allData) {
              res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://hostname:8183/");
        res.json({ message3: allData });
        });
      res.send(send response to html);
    })
    var server  = app.listen(8183, function(){
      console.log('Server listening on port '+ server.address().port) 
    });
```

My todo.js is

```
    var connection = require('../connection');
    var data = {},obj={};
    var d = new Date();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();

    obj.getUsrCnt = function getUsrCnt(callback) {
            connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
                con.query(query1, function(err, result) {
                  con.release();
                  data.usrs_cnt = result[0].some;
                })
            });
        }
    obj.getTotlAmt =  function getTotlAmt(callback) {
            connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
                con.query(query2, function(err, result) {
                    con.release();
                    data.total_amt = result[0].some1;
                })
            });
        }

    obj.getTotlOrdrCnt = function getTotlOrdrCnt(callback) {
            connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
                con.query(query3, function(err, result) {
                    con.release();
                    data.total_orders = result[0].some2;
                })
            });
        }
        .
        .
        . functions go on
exports.class1 = obj;
```

Getting undefined in the promise all and unable to render to the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the code you wrote, but as I understand you want to call all the functions, get all the results and return back to the user?

so you can use many libraries that waits for several calls for example, promise based:

```
 Promise.all([todo.getUsrCnt('dontcare'), todo.getTotlAmt('dontcate')])
    .then(function(allData) {
        // All data available here in the order it was called.
    });
```

as for your updated code, you are not returning the data as promises, you assigning it to the local variable.

this is how your methods should look:

```
 obj.getUsrCnt = function getUsrCnt(callback) {
        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
             connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
                    if(err) {
                        return reject(err);
                    }
                    con.query(query1, function(err, result) {
                        con.release();
                        resolve(result[0].some);
                     })
                 });
        });
        return promise;

    }
```

as you can see here, I am creating a new promise and returning it in the main function.
Inside the new promise I have 2 methods: "resolve", "reject"
one is for the data and one is for errors.

so when you use the promise like this:

```
returnedPromise.then(function(data) {
    //this data is what we got from resolve
}).catch(function(err) {
    //this err is what we got from reject
});
```

you can see that a promise can or resolved or rejected,
do this to all the methods, and then you start seeing data

Comment: Thanks for the response.but cant get the output when used promise.all

Comment: Modified the code ,please check . Getting the output like app js [{},{},{},{},{}]

Comment: @yaswanth please review the updated post, and see how to use the promises

Comment: Thanks for the help and it worked. Can you tell me how to use promise all in the express routing???.

Comment: What do you mean on the Express routing?  Create another post and elaborate there....

Comment: When multiple systems access my url,not getting the output getting the error (failed)net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.How to overcome that